# How do I erase Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is the only OS on my laptop. I have spent alot of time researching on how to format the drive along with Ubuntu OS. Kindly help me do this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to install other OS and before doing that you want to wipe out your hard drive? Is that the case?

Comment: I want to format the drive, then install Windows 7.